# Import ColdFusion Code into Enterprise Architect

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, enterprise-architect

My group has a number of ColdFusion Classes (CFC files) which we want to reverse engineer into Enterprise Architect. We currently have code we use to generate ColdFusion code from our UML models in Enterprise Architect, but we would really like to be able to import the existing ColdFusion classes into Enterprise Architect, too.

Does anyone know of an xml file we can import into our model to let us do this? Or suggestions on how to create our own?

Comment: I am not familiar with Enterprise Architect. Can it import from a WSDL?  ColdFusion CFC's can automatically create a WSDL file (when they are published as a web service). [Producing WSDL files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78a6.html)

Comment: You can also use GetComponentMetaData() to get all the info you'd need. I've used this in the past to scan all CFCs in an application and inspect them in order to generate documentation. The same approach would work to generate XMI or similar class metadata

Answer (score 1):

EA has native support for WSDL import, but not for ColdFusion.

However, one of the big new features in version 10 is the ability to define your own language for reverse engineering (doing the same for forward engineering has been an EA feature for a long time).

So you could write your own import module as part of an "MDG Technology." Check the help file under Extending UML Models -- MDG Technology SDK -- Grammar Framework. It's not a five-minute job by any means, but it can be done.